# How to resolve ClassCastException using Mockito/PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am in a situation where I need to Mock two static methods using PowerMocklito. It gives me a mocked object for the first line of code but then the same method is called again but this time it is returning a different object and this throws `ClassCastException`.

Method Under test

```
ESignatureJaxBContextFactory context = (ESignatureJaxBContextFactory) AppContext.getBean("jaxbContextFactory");
/// More code
DocusignRESTClient client = (DocusignRESTClient) AppContext.getBean("restServiceClient");
```

Junit

```
private ESignatureJaxBContextFactory eSignatureJaxBContextFactory;
eSignatureJaxBContextFactory = mock( ESignatureJaxBContextFactory.class );

PowerMockito.when( AppContext.getBean( any( String.class ) ) ).thenReturn( eSignatureJaxBContextFactory );
```

So above line of code returns me mock context, but I get an exception when it tries to fetch client. How can I test this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mocking `AppContext.getBean` for `any( String.class )`
Try this:

```
PowerMockito.when(AppContext.getBean("jaxbContextFactory"))
            .thenReturn(eSignatureJaxBContextFactory);
PowerMockito.when(AppContext.getBean("restServiceClient"))
            .thenReturn(docusignRESTClient);
```

In this case when `AppContext.getBean` is invoked with parameter `"jaxbContextFactory"` it will return `eSignatureJaxBContextFactory` but not for any other parameters. So you also need to mock invocation with parameter `"restServiceClient"`.

Other way of testing it is to provide a set of consecutive return values:

```
PowerMockito.when(AppContext.getBean(any(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(eSignatureJaxBContextFactory, docusignRESTClient);
```

In this case you still mock any invocation of `AppContext.getBean` with any String value as parameter, but are telling mockito to return `eSignatureJaxBContextFactory` on first invocation and to return `docusignRESTClient` on second and any further invocations.

Comment: Both solutions worked for me. Your solutions are so logical and simple. Thank you so much.